# How to get two or more json_encode php echos via Ajax?

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

```
   $errMsgUsername="";
    $errMsgPassword="";

    if ($_POST['username']==""){
     $errMsgUsername="Username is null";
    }
    if ($_POST['password']==""){
     $errMsgPassword="Password is null";
    }

    echo json_encode(['errMsgUsername'=>$errMsgUsername,'errMsgPassword',=>$errMsgPassword]); // json response 1

$success = "";
if ($_POST['username']!="" && $_POST['password']!=""){
$success = "Form data available";
json_encode(['success'=>$success]); // json response 2
}
$.ajax({
              url: $url,
              type: $type,
              data :formData,
              cache: false,
              dataType:"json",
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function(response){
                //if fields null, the response has to display here.
                $('.div_username').html(response.errMsgUsername);
                $('.div_password').html(response.errMsgPassword);

                //if fields are not null the response has to display here/
                $('.div').html(response.success);

              }
            });
```

The problem is when i submit the form while (the Username and Password are null), the ajax response is displaying in the Div's as expected. But when I submit the form while (Username and Password are not null with data), the ajax response is not displaying in the $('.div').html(response.success);.
When I see check the ajax request under developer tools it shows that the request is successful, and the the response also came back like this {"errMsgUsername":" ","errMsgPassword":" "}{"success":"Form data available"}.

So the problem here is the ajax response has two **two** json_encode responses. So how to manage this two responses successfully?

Comment: Why you need the two same responses?

Comment: I don't need same responses. how to make it one depend on the situation above?  @NitinDhomse

Comment: @JomyJoseph can you show me that in a clear view? as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started on this response before Jomy replied you, posting it as i cleaned up your code a bit, might be useful.

```
<?php

  $errors = array();

  if (empty($_POST['username'])){
   $errors['errMsgUsername']="Username is null";
  }
  if (empty($_POST['password'])){
   $errors['errMsgPassword']="Password is null";
  }

  if( !empty( $errors ) )
    return json_encode( $errors );

  // If failed, which means we succeeded.
  $success = array(
    'success' => 'Form data available'
  );

  return json_encode($success);
```

Comment: I got to say that your comment should be directed towards yourself, for your comment. The user explicitly mentioned that he knows what the problem is, just not how to solve it. If you understand the problem, then you also understand the solution when it's provided in cleartext. Your comment would be valid, and my answer would be different, if the OP indicated that he didn't know what was going on, which is not the case.

Comment: On StackOverflow we don't answer questions just for OP. We answer questions for anyone who reads the question, hence _not as useful for future readers_. Someone else coming here with the same problem may not understand your solution, as you actually haven't explained what you changed in the code or how you fixed it.

Comment: On StackOverflow we also edit other people's answer to improve it if we feel it wasn't satisfying enough, what we don't do on StackOverflow tho, is downvote just to downvote and rant in the comment area. Besides, future visitors with the same issue will understand perfectly fine, why? Because what you want me to do, explain what's wrong, the OP has already done. And for a future visitor to know if my answer can help them, they first need to read and understand the OPs question and problem to identify it and understand that it's the same as theirs.

Comment: I didn't "downvote just to downvote", I clicked the "This answer is not useful", because it's not. It's a code-only answer. I'm not going to edit your answer and explain what **_you_** did, it's much easier for me to just downvote and move on. Though if you edited your answer and explained it, I would be happy to remove my downvote :)

Comment: And it's much easier for me to simply ignore what you say and not take it into consideration at all. After all, you're just trolling here.

Comment: You certainly are welcome to do that. I don't know why people keep saying I'm trolling - you definitely are not the first person to say that. Maybe you should have a peek at the several meta posts regarding this issue. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258673/can-code-only-answers-be-high-quality https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers (That's not all of them)

Comment: Perhaps you should then take that into consideration? "It's everyone else, not me", is usually never the case.

Comment: I'm going to move on as I've spent too much time here. You don't have to follow my advice, I don't really care. I could have just downvoted and moved on, but I wanted to tell you _why_ I was downvoting so you had an opportunity to improve your answer.

Comment: And I'm taking the time to yell you **why** that's not necessary, but you're not listening, to busy trolling.

Comment: For the record, I'm not saying you should explain the problem _again_ (That would be unnecessary, I agree with you there), I'm simply saying you should state what you did to fix it. What code you added, what code you took away, what you changed to make it work as OP expects. Even just commenting the line of code you added would be a huge improvement on the post for those developers that are not as experienced as OP may be so they can _see clearly_ what the actual fix is in the answer.